# Method returns before executing all threads even though executor.awaitTermination is used

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, executorservice

I have a method which takes number of threads to work and then executes the run() method for each thread accordingly as shown below

```
public static Map<String, Integer> execute(int thread_count) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(thread_count);
        File folder = new File("logFiles/");       
        Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(folder, null, true);     
        for(File file : files){
            //For rach file in folder execute run()
            System.out.println(file.getName());
            executor.submit(new Runner((file.getAbsolutePath())));
        } 
        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception "+ e + " in CountLines.execute()");
        }
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: Runner.lineCountMap.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : : " + entry.getValue());
        }
        return Runner.lineCountMap;// printing after all the threads finish executing
    }
```

And the run method is defined as below:

```
public void run() {
        try {
            count = countLines(file);//get number of lines in file
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception "+ e + " in Runner.run()");
        }
        //count number of lines in each file and add to map
        lineCountMap.put(file, count);
    }
```

As I have used executor.awaitTermination in execute() method above, I am expecting my lineCountMap to be populated with all the filesnames as key and line count as values. But it seems the lineCountMap is being returned before all threads are executed.

```
For the following files:
    logtest.2014­-07-­04.log
    logtest.2014­-07-­02.log
    logtest.2014­-07-­01.log
    logtest.2014­-07-­03.log

Expected Output:

lineCountMap:
/logtest.2014­-07-­01.log : : 4
/logtest.2014­-07-­02.log : : 8
/logtest.2014­-07-­03.log : : 2
/logtest.2014­-07-­04.log : : 1

Actual Output:

lineCountMap:
/logtest.2014­-07-­01.log : : 4
/logtest.2014­-07-­03.log : : 2
/logtest.2014­-07-­04.log : : 0
```

Here **I am missing content for /logtest.2014­-07-­02.log** and also the value for /logtest.2014­-07-­04.log is shown 0 when it is 1

Comment: Is `lineCountMap` a `ConcurrentHashMap` (like it should, being accessed concurrently by several threads...), or a simple `java.util.HashMap` ?

Comment: Hi @OlivierCroisier it is a simple `java.util.HashMap`. Each thread is accessing independent key in `lineCountMap`, so do I need my map to be Concurrent?

Comment: Yes, you still do for proper data publication in memory. Change your `HashMap` to a `ConcurrentHashMap` and test again.

Comment: Thanks @OlivierCroisier. It worked! I needed a `TreeMap` and so `ConcurrentSkipListMap` did the trick.

Comment: If you want to understand why a simple `HashMap` wasn't enough, you really should read the book "Java Concurrency In Practice" by Brian Goetz, Doug Lea and al. That's really a must-read !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `lineCountMap` to a `ConcurrentHashMap` solved the issue. Thanks to Oliver Croisier for the solution as discussed in comments section.